# Why an array key-value sets in the end of an array instead of a specific place?

Tags: php

to be precise I have:

```
$foo = [1, 4, 1, 5, 8, 1, 3, 5, 1, 4, 1, 3, 7, 2];
sort($foo);
$bar = array_count_values($foo);

for ($i = 1; $i < count($bar); $i++) {
    if (!isset($bar[$i])) {
        $bar[$i] = 0;
    }
}
```

Actual result:

```
array (size=8)
  1 => int 5
  2 => int 1
  3 => int 2
  4 => int 2
  5 => int 2
  7 => int 1
  8 => int 1
  6 => int 0
```

Expected result:

```
array (size=8)
  1 => int 5
  2 => int 1
  3 => int 2
  4 => int 2
  5 => int 2
  6 => int 0
  7 => int 1
  8 => int 1
```

Why my key value pair `6 => 0` appears in the bottom of an array instead of a specific place?

Comment: array_count_values returns an associative array (unless you pass in sequential numeric values starting with zero), even if all of the values are numeric, so new values are appended regardless of the key's relation to other keys in the array.

Comment: if you predefine `i=1` your loop should look like this `for ($i = 1; $i <= count($bar); $i++) { ... }` else the last element in the array is omitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are appending a new value to the array.

To "fix" that, use `ksort($bar);`.

As @Rob Ruchte wrote in comments, the array returned by `array_count_values()` is associative, which means there is no order with the keys.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

> Returns an associative array of values from array as keys and their count as value.